# Prove convergence in distribution, probability, or quadratic mean for a sequence of binary variables that depend on another binary variable

Tags: self-study, expected-value, convergence, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $X$ has the support set $\{1, -1\}$, and $P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = 0.5$.

Suppose that $X_n$ has the support set $\{X, e^n\}$, and

$P(X_n = X) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$

$P(X_n = e^n) = \frac{1}{n}$

a) Does $X_n$ converge in distribution to $X$?

b) Does $X_n$ converge in probability to $X$?

c) Does $X_n$ converge in quadratic mean to $X$?

I know that, if the answer to c) is "Yes", then the answer to b) is also "Yes", which implies that the answer to a) is also "Yes".  Thus, I tried to prove c) affirmatively.

I want to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[(X - X_n)^2] = 0 \\$$

I know that

$E[(X - X_n)^2] = E[X^2 - 2XX_n + X_n^2]$

Let's now separate the 3 terms.

i) The first term is $E(X^2) = 1^2 (0.5) + (-1)^2 (0.5) = 1 \\$

ii) For the second term, I know that

$E(XX_n)$

$ = E[E(XX_n|X)]$

$ = E[XE(X_n|X)]$

$ = E[X(1 - \frac{1}{n})]$

$ = E(X) - \frac{E(X)}{n}$

$ = 0 - \frac{0}{n} = 0$

iii) I am unsure about the third term.  I think that it is

$E(X_n^2) = X^2 (1 - \frac{1}{n}) + (e^n)^2 \frac{1}{n} = X^2 - \frac{X^2}{n} + \frac{e^{2n}}{n}$

Is this correct?  If so, then it seems like $X_n$ does not converge in quadratic mean to $X$.  If so, then I don't know how to answer a) and b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, $X_n$ does not converge in quadratic mean to $X$ as you already show.

For converge in probability:

$$\Pr(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) <\Pr(X_n \ne X) = \Pr(X_n=e^n) = \frac 1n$$

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \Pr(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) = 0$

Therefore, $X_n$  converges in probability to $X$.

Comment: Why is $P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) < P(X_n \neq X)$?

Comment: Because if $|X_n-X|> \epsilon$ implies $X_n \ne X$.

Comment: Ah...I think that I understand you now.  If there is some positive difference between $X_n$ and $X$, then there is no way that $X_n$ can be the same thing as $X$.  OK, that makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: should be " If there is some difference between ..."

Answer (score 0):

I think $E[XE(X_n|X)]$ should be computed as $E[X[(1-\dfrac1n)X+\dfrac{e^n}{n}]]\\=(1-\dfrac1n)E(X^2)+\dfrac{e^n}{n}E(X)\\=1-\dfrac1n$

However, I agree that $X_n$ does not converge to $X$ in quadratic mean.